# Using Simple Injector to register lazy parameters by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, simple-injector

My Service classes have two IRepository instance(**ICacheRepository** and **ISqlRepository**),  ICacheRepository implementations always use in services, but ISqlRepository implementations sometimes use.
I register all implementations of ***ICacheRepository*** interface in Simple Injector by Reflection:

```
var registrations = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
   .Where(type => type.IsClass && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(ICacheRepository))
   .Select(type => new { Interface = type.GetInterfaces().First(), Implementation = type });

foreach (var reg in registrations)
{
    container.Register(reg.Interface, reg.Implementation, Lifestyle.Transient);
}
```

I found [Lazy Register](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#lazy) solution to registering one instance of an interface. But I want register all implementations of ***ISqlRepository*** interface in lazy mode by Reflection. my desired solution is:

```
var registrations = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
   .Where(type => type.IsClass && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(ISqlRepository))
   .Select(type => new { Interface = type.GetInterfaces().First(), Implementation = type });

foreach (var reg in registrations)
{
    container.Register(() => new Lazy<reg.Interface>(container.GetInstance<typeof(reg.Implementation) >), Lifestyle.Transient);
}
```

Is there any solution to the described problem?

Comment: "I want register all implementations in lazy mode". That's a serious smell. Why do you need services to be built lazily?

Comment: It's a general sample, i want register some implementations in lazy mode and others in normal mode.

Comment: If registrations are lazy, this means that your services do too much in their constructor, while ctors shoukd be simple. If you would have one or two lazy services, that should be much, so you can easily register those lazy services by hand.

Comment: But the usual warnings a side, here is an example of auto-resolving lazy's: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/SimpleInjector.CodeSamples/ResolvingFactoriesExtensions.cs

Comment: @Steven thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152386/discussion-between-m-rezaeyan-and-steven).